# iOS Swift UITextField password rules

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to implement password generation accordingly to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/customizing_password_autofill_rules

Unfortunately, I can't implement a custom rule "at least 2 digits in the password". Does anybody know how to implement it ?

Password rules can be tested [here](https://developer.apple.com/password-rules/).

I've tried these ones, but it doesn't work.

```
required: upper; 
required: lower; 
required: digit;
required: [1234567890];
```

```
required: upper; 
required: lower; 
required: digit;
required: digit;
```

Comment: can you add some code to let us know what have you tried so far

Comment: @GulfamKhan I've updated original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use minimum length for that purpose, here is an example from apple docs

```
let newPasswordTextField = UITextField()
newPasswordTextField.passwordRules = UITextInputPasswordRules(descriptor: required: upper; required: lower; required: digit; minlength: 2;")
```

Comment: “minlength: 2;” rule is applied for whole password, not specific case. You can look on generated passwords in the validation tool https://developer.apple.com/password-rules/

Comment: you want to apply that on just digits section of the password?

Comment: Yes, I want to require >= 2 digits in a generated password

Comment: I don't think thats possible, I'll definitely get back to you if I find anything, but according to my limited knowledge that's not possible